# Delete 4 consecutive lines after a match in a file

Tags: bash, awk, replace, sed, dns

I am in the process of deleting around 33k of zones on a DNS server. I used this awk string to find the matching rows in my zones.conf file:

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/domain.com/' zones.conf
```

This give me the output down below, which is what I want.

```
zone "domain.com" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db/domain.com";
};
```

The problem I am facing now, is to delete the 4 lines.
Is it possible to use sed or awk to perform this action?

EDIT:
I have decided that I want to run in in a while loop. List.txt contain the domain which I want to remove from the zones.conf file.
Every row is defined as the variable '${line}' and is defined in the awk (which was provided by "l'L'l")
The string was originaly:

```
awk -v OFS='\n\n' '/domain.com/{n=4}; n {n--; next}; 1' < zones.conf > new.conf
```

I tried to modify it so it would accept a variable, but without result:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
        awk -v OFS='\n\n' '/"'${line}'"/{n=4}; n {n--; next}; 1' zones.conf > new.conf

done<list.txt
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '! /domain.com/' zones.conf` ?

Comment: This seems to display all the non matching lines.

Comment: `replace the 4 lines with nothing`: I (mis)interpreted that you wanted to remove these 4 matching lines...

Comment: Make changes to the original file ?

Comment: I have edited the original post a little. I want to delete thoose 4 lines.

But I have no idea how you interpreted that I would want to print all non matching lines instead :)

Comment: I am not working in the original file, is that answers your question @sjsam. Just a copy.

Comment: This question is still incomplete w/o mentioning how `list.txt` would like. Please ask a [mcve]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite easy with `sed`:

```
 sed -i '/zone "domain.com"/,+4d' zones.conf
```

With a variable:

```
 sed -i '/zone "'$domain'"/,+4d' zones.conf
```

Full working example:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read domain
do
    sed -i '/zone "'$domain'"/,+4d' zones.conf
done<list.txt
```

Comment: Thank you.
I can't upvote you yet, not enough reputation ;)

Comment: No harm in putting  `$DOMAIN` in double quotes. Regarding `+4d` , it may not work if the zone record spans more than4 lines, otherwise ++

Comment: Also it is not encouraged to use full uppercase variables in your scripts as they are reserved for the system.

Answer (score 2):

My `sed` solution would be

```
sed '/zone "domain.com"/{:l1;/};\n$/!{N;bl1};d}' file > newfile 
#But the above would be on the slower end if you're dealing with 33k zones
```

For inplace editing use the `-i` option with `sed` like below :

```
sed -i.bak '/zone "domain.com"/{:l1;/};\n$/!{N;bl1};d}' file
#Above will create a backup of the original file with a '.bak' extension
```

**For using variables**

```
#!/bin/bash
while read domain #capitalized variables are usually reserved for the system
do
    sed '/zone "'"${domain}"'"/{:l1;/};\n$/!{N;bl1};d}' file > newfile
    # for inplace edit use below
    # sed -i.bak '/zone "'"${domain}"'"/{:l1;/};\n$/!{N;bl1};d}' file
done<list.txt
```

Comment: This works, 
But I am unable to get it to work with variables:
 sed '/zone "${line}"/{:l1;/};/!{N;bl1};d}' zones.conf > newfile

Comment: @Orphans : see the update and do accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: The sed you provided does work flawless. 
But it does not seems to work in a while loop for some reason.

I will provide an update when everything is working as it should.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to modify your existing `awk` command to remove a specified number of lines once the match is found, for example:

```
awk -v OFS='\n\n' '/domain.com/{n=4}; n {n--; next}; 1' < zones.conf > new.conf
```

This would remove 4 lines after the initial `domain.com` is found, giving you the correct newlines.

**Output**:

```
zone "other.com" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db/other.com";
};


zone "foobar.com" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db/foobar.com";
};
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, It does work!
But it should be possible to use a variable instead on domain.com?
awk -v OFS='\n\n' '/${line}/{n=4}; n {n--; next}; 1' zones.conf > new.conf

It is not working thou, but I guess I should "wrap it" inside some "/'?

Comment: Make these changes to your while loop: `while read -r line`, and `awk -v OFS='\n\n' '/'"${line}"'/{n=4}; n {n--; next}; 1'` ... you've got the double quotes placed incorrectly.